# Is there limited space in the Arrivals area?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

If I save VIPs in the arrival area, they will keep filling space. Is the Arrivals area limited to 5 spots which I can see, or will that expand? If I save 5 VIPs, will that prevent more VIPs from generating, or will they continue to spawn and allow me to save, or use them?

Comment: That's a good set of questions - though I would only be able to answer the *unlocking more space* question when I am near end-game.   Which could be a month or so, but right now it looks like we are limited to just 5 slots.   I can test this when I have more VIPs though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this out sooner than I thought I would be able to with a string of VIPs being generated.

After storing 5 VIPs in the arrivals area, VIPs do not stop generating. If you try and store a 6th one, the game tells you the Arrivals Level is full, and you can't hold any more. You have to use the VIP given to you immediately.

[image]